# Expanding a list based on a number per line

Tags: expand

So I have a file similar to this

`A 1 foo bar 1
A 1 foo bar 2
B 3 foo bar 5
B 3 foo bar 6`

Where the first column is an ID, the second column is the number of times I need the line repeated. The output should look like this

`A foo bar 1
A foo bar 2
B foo bar 5
B foo bar 6
C foo bar 5
C foo bar 6
D foo bar 5
D foo bar 6`

However, since the files I am trying to use are rather big, the expanding is ultra slow. Any ideas? :)

EDIT1: Code I did, I did have two inputs, one file with the columns i showed before and one with just IDs and counts separated by a dash.

`for ID in $(cat $ID_File);do
 grep "^$ID[^0-9]" $IN > temp2.txt 
 Cycles=$(echo $ID| sed 's/.*-//')
 for i in $(seq 1 1 $Cycles);do
  cut -f2- temp2.txt| awk '{print '$Start_ID'"\t"$0}'>> $OUT
  Start_ID=$(( $Start_ID + 1 ))
 done
done`

Comment: How can we improve code that we can't see? You need to show what you tried. See [ask].

Comment: Added code now :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer! Instead of looking through the file several times with `grep` I used the following Python script that goes through the file just once.

```
FILE='A.txt'
ID=''
Prefix='A'

Number=1
First=1
Current=[]
OUT='B.txt'
f=open(File,'w')

for line in open(FILE):
 line1=line.split('\t')
 if ID!=line1[0] and First==0:
  ID=line1[0]
  for i in range(0,int(Current[0][1])):
   for j in range(0,len(Current)):
    f.write(' '.join([Prefix+str(Number)]+Current[j][2:]))
  Number=Number+1
  Current=[]
  Current.append(line1) 
 elif ID!=line1[0] and First==1:
  ID=line1[0]
  First=0
  Current.append(line1)
 elif ID==line1[0]:
  Current.append(line1)
```

Not the most elegant way to do it, but it gets the job done fast relatively quickly.